# Blog Post Associated with category

Tags: php, magento, fishpig

Hi I have been trying for a few hours now but I can't seem to figure it out for myself, I'm using the fish pig word-press plugin and I want to display word press blog post Associated with Magento category. There is a tab in the magento back end for doing so but I can't get it to display in the front-end

```
<action method="setEntity"><type><![CDATA[cms_page]]></type></action>
```

I think the key to getting it to display is the "set Entity" but I can't get it right.

I have tried to change it to many things but it still ain't working

Comment: Are you using a custom theme?  If the Fishpig plugin includes custom template files and layout XML files, you may need to copy these to your theme folder (if your theme is not included under the /default/ tree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to display associated blog posts on the Magento category page, this isn't possible. At the time of writing, associating a blog post with a Magento category is just a quick way to associate that post with all of the products in the category.

I will be working on an update in the future that will allow you to show associations on the category page, but currently this would require some custom development on your part. To do this, you would need to query the database to extract the post/category relationships and then load a post collection based on that.

Comment: Aw OK well i just wait till that feature is added, and thank you for the very quick reply Ben.